# laravel 7 artisan key:generate not working

Tags: php, laravel

when i run  `php artisan key:generate` in cmd it's return

```
file_get_contents(/project/positiv/core/vendor/psy//.env): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

at

```
/project/positiv/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/KeyGenerateCommand.php:96
{
    file_put_contents($this->laravel->environmentFilePath(), preg_replace(
        $this->keyReplacementPattern(),
        'APP_KEY='.$key,
        file_get_contents($this->laravel->environmentFilePath())
    ));
}
```

I am trying to generate `APP_KEY`!!!

Comment: do you have env file in root of the project ?

Comment: no. it's a sub folder form root

Answer (score 4):

At first generate APP_KEY with the command `php artisan key:generate --show`. It will print contents on your terminal which you can copy and paste wherever you want. In this case APP_KEY=`value` on your .env file.

Generated Key format will be something like base64:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to run artisan command outside the project.

Make sure your terminal is targeting the exact project you want to trigger

Comment: i am sure it was project root.